# How to inject javascript code in jmeter WebDriver sample?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, dynatrace

i'm using Webdriver sample and selenium in java to interact the element of a webpage. I need to perform the call to a javascript function in the webdriver sample in java.
They asked me to identify the user by using a javascript function that is:

dtrum.identifyUser(tagValue)

basing on what is written here:
https://www.dynatrace.com/news/blog/accelerating-functional-test-automation-analysis-with-selenium-and-dynatrace/

So i'm trying to perform the call of that function by importing the library:

import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;

and then call:
WDS.browser.executeScript("dtrum.identifyUser('user')");

but i get:

Error in method invocation: Method executeScript( java.lang.String ) not found in class'org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver'

I've also tryied with:
((JavascriptExecutor) webdriver).executeScript("dtrum.identifyUser('user')");

but i get:

Target exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast void value to org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor

Since i am really new at it what i'm doing wrong? How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

> i'm using Webdriver sample and selenium in java

You don't have "java" in the WebDriver Sampler.

If you mean this `java`

[image]

**it's not Java, it's [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) interpreter** which is not 100% compatible with Java.

I would suggest switching to `groovy` because:

- Groovy is more compatible with modern Java features, valid Java code in 99.9% of cases will be valid Groovy code while Beanshell doesn't support generics, diamond operators, etc. See [Groovy Syntax](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html) for more details
- [Groovy performs much better comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)
- Groovy adds a lot of "syntax sugar" [on top of Java SDK](https://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html)
- [It's recommended to use Groovy for scripting since JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)

So you will be able to call your `WDS.browser.executeScript("dtrum.identifyUser('user')");` function without having to change anything in your code.

Comment: really thank you for your reply. I've changed as you said the script language from java to groovy, but when i run i've got that error: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: user for class: Script2 
what i have to fix?